# How can I load and access content (buttons, sliders, etc.) from my XIB's windows into my python script? - PyObj-C

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc

Right now I am having trouble figuring out in my [PyObj-C](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/) project within Objective-C how I can use the class methods for the contents in NSView in windows in my XIB file. For example finding and changing via it's methods my slider (NSSlider) or date picker (NSDatePicker), it's state or colors or whatever with instance methods properties etc.

I am doing this in python scripts. Right here in my `WindowController.py` and `AppDelegate.py` I have some IBActions and in the Delegate I instaniate my xib file's nib with initWithWindowNibName:

```py
# AppDelegate.py
class AppDelegate(Cocoa.NSObject):
    app = Cocoa.NSApplication.sharedApplication()

    viewController = mainWindow.alloc().initWithWindowNibName_("shoutout_main")
    viewController.showWindow_(viewController)
```

[Here is my XIB](https://github.com/leifadev/shoutout/blob/main/src/shoutout_main.xib) and here's a [picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNonW.png) too for reference. I also code in my [`WindowController.py`](https://github.com/leifadev/shoutout/blob/2abc508f41015e472a998eb933b3cf35df3274f0/src/WindowController.py) for the main window here:

```py
class mainWindow(prefWindow):
    """
    Main Controller for main window, inherits from prefWindow class
    """

    def __init__(self):
        word = objc.IBOutlet()
        definition = objc.IBOutlet()

    @objc.IBAction
    def helplink_(self, sender):
        url = "https://github.com/leifadev/shoutout/wiki"
        print(f"{url} opened!")
        link = Cocoa.NSURL.alloc().initWithString_(url)
        Cocoa.NSWorkspace.alloc().openURL_(link)
```

I have tried some ways to somehow access the contents of my window or view that contain the buttons, sliders, combo boxes, etc. via IBOutlets. I also tried to find class methods in the View Management category of Apple Docs that had methods to give me access to the View or Window contents, but I don't think I have found anything that worked or could work.

However, I think I found a instance method that will get me what I need which is [loadView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434405-loadview?language=objc) and [loadWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1535137-loadwindow?language=objc):

> Instantiates a view from a nib file and sets the value of the view
> property.

> Loads the receiver’s window from the nib file.

I think I need these. Am I correct? What should I do from here?
I am sort of new to using Apple's Interface Builder and Frameworks in a since still.

Comment: I’m not seeing any outlet connections in the Interface Editor.  Declaring an IBOutlet lets it show up in the Interface Editor, but from there you need to connect the various UI objects to its matching outlet.

Comment: @red_menace Interesting... I believe I just have to put  an IBOutlet into a variable and connect it, and then I can use the methods, I guess it's that simple after all, I'll give an update

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it wasn't that complicated at all. All you have to do to access and change UI element's properties etc. (e.g. an NSSlider, NSTextFieldCell, anything) you need to make it in an IBOutlet.

Very simple.

**1.** First make a variable with a name you want to call your UI element as:

```py
class mainWindow(prefWindow):

    definitionField = objc.IBOutlet() 
    """
    This will be linked in the Interface builder 
    to a NSTextField for a definition of a word
    """
```

**2.** Go into your Interface Builder for your XIB in Xcode, then drag your Outlet to whatever element on your window/view you want to access and change within your code...

[image]

**3.** Back at your code your free to use it's instance methods or properties and so on! You can run in as is or possibly put it in a IBAction:

```py
    @objc.IBAction
    def changeDefinition_(self, sender):
        self.definitionField.setStringValue_("Squirrel: A fuzzy small animal that eats acorns")
        self.definitionField.setEditable_(False)
        print("Set string, and the text field is now locked...")
```

I used the instance properties editable and stringValue from Foundation

I have one question that I am working on. How can I use their instance methods?

Something like this?

```py
        x = self.complexity.alloc().init().tickMarkValueAtIndex_()
        print(x)
```

Comment: The outlet variable you set up is the reference to the object.  The object is the receiver of the message (method call), so you would just do something like `x = selectDay.tickMarkValueAtIndex_(0)` (`SomeClass.alloc().init()` creates a new object).  Note that an action’s `sender` parameter is the control that is calling it, for example `sender.setEditable_(False)`.

Comment: @red_menace I see, I tried taking putting the Slider into an outlet, then using `x = self.complexity_slider.tickMarkValueAtIndex_(0)` and did `print(x)` within a IBAction, however I got nothing returned pr printed :(

Comment: The method didn’t return anything?  Is the slider target set to the correct class?  You might want to update the GitHub repo so people can see what you are doing.

Comment: @red_menace I updated my repo, does not seem to be working, the slider is NSSlider class by default. [New `WindowController.py`](https://github.com/leifadev/shoutout/blob/2abc508f41015e472a998eb933b3cf35df3274f0/src/WindowController.py), new XIB