# PyObj-C/Objective-C: instance methods for my IBOutlet objects are not returning the objects values, dateValue: etc

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, xib, pyobjc

Currently I am trying to access really any of my object's in my XIBs object values.
For example getting the NSData object or value from the current Date Picker in my preferences window (to see what date is currently selected).

I have the following code in a IBAction from a button I've been pressing to get the current value of a date picker using the [`dateValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdatepicker/1527606-datevalue?language=objc) method which returns a NSData object.

```py
@objc.IBAction
def selectDay_(self, sender):
    print("IBAction triggered!")
    date = self.weekSelectButton.dateValue()
    print(date)
    
    # Have tried .dateValue_ and .dateValue too just to make sure
```

When run it I get nothing returned. Not even a blank line using `print()` in console or something. Hopefully I am doing this the correct way, someone else on [another thread of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74350448/11805086) recently was puzzled on why this code wouldn't work as well (seen at bottom comments of my answer). Kind of stuck here...

Here is my [src/](https://github.com/leifadev/shoutout/blob/main/src). Please take a look at specifically if you want to the `prefController.py` (window controller for my preferences window), and the XIB itself.

Anyone have a clue of what I could be messing up here? My situation, in part of me using PyObj-C and just my project setup seems to be more obscure to the search engines. So I have ended up here.

Comment: Does `print()` print anything if the value is nil?  Have you tried using the `sender` parameter (which will be the date picker)?

Comment: Is `selectDay_` called? Is `"IBAction triggered!"` printed?

Comment: @red_menace I am very stupid, I was using the wrong IBOutlet, which was the `weekSelectButton` which was a NSPopupButton. It's working fine now...

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was using the wrong IBOutlet for the wrong button. I was referring to a `NSPopUpBotton` outlet which was `self.weekSelectButton`, when I was actually needing to refer to the `self.datePicker` variable in my code.

So to summarize the following code changes were made. If your have a problem that I had please remember to check if it's the right outlet!

```py
weekSelectButton = objc.IBOutlet()
datePicker = objc.IBOutlet()
@objc.IBAction
def selectDay_(self, sender):
    print("IBAction triggered!")
    date = self.weekSelectButton.dateValue()
    print(date)
```

Fixed code:

```py
weekSelectButton = objc.IBOutlet()
datePicker = objc.IBOutlet()
@objc.IBAction
def selectDay_(self, sender):
    print("IBAction triggered!")
    date = self.datePicker.dateValue() # Changed to my datePicker outlet tied to a NSDatePicker instead of the NSPopUp
    print(date)
```

Again, simple mistake made by me referring the wrong outlet haha